# Haskell generate list of lists

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am preparing for test in haskell and I found a task from last test where was given to generate infinite list lists.

```
generate :: Num n => n -> [[n]]
```

where list is n-tuple, n is from parameter.

moreover the lists has to be sorted.

For exaple:

```
generate 2 = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[0,3],....]
```

I have to use only basic functions.

I know that it surely is simple, but I dont know how to do it and I also can't find it on the internet.

I will be really glad for any help.

Comment: Infinite tuples are not possible in Haskell, that would be something like `type tup = (X, tup)`. GHC rejects such infinite types. `[[n]]` is the type of a _list_, which can indeed be infinite (but only at runtime; it's perfectly finite to the type checker).

Comment: Not really; you need dependent types to specify that the return value is a list of lists of length 2, etc. Even if you could, `Num` is an overly broad constraint; you can't have a list of length 1.5 (or a 1.5-tuple).

Comment: I think it is clear from the provided example that the OP wants to generate an infinite list of _lists_ - not tuples.

Comment: You want a list-of-lists. There are no tuples in the type `n -> [[n]]`. Also, `Int n => ...` is not Haskell, unless `Int` is a custom class -- was that `Num n => ...` instead?

Comment: This isn't generating tuples, it's generating a list of lists. Tuples are by definition sorted, and so are lists; the difference is that lists are homogeneously typed, and tuples can have different types as long as they are of equal length and types are in the same positions.

Comment: Ok that is what i want.

Comment: But these lists are called tuples, aren´t they?

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks for good advice, I am trying to write it about hour and I really didn't know how to do it, however one of my frieds helped me so now i know it but have no permision to show his solution. Next time if you don't want to help, please don't comment.

Comment: ok, I understand what you said you don't have to say it again, it's not constructive. I needed to understand the way how to do it, because of my test.

Comment: You say the list has to be sorted. What order does it have to be in? How would it look for generate 3 or 4?

Comment: @leftaroundabout and if you think that it is so easy you could help me.

Comment: firstly by max member and than lexikografical like in example.

Comment: `allTuplesWithMaxElem k maxElem = filter (elem maxElem) (allTuples k maxElem) ` this can do it i think.

Comment: so `generate k = concatMap (allTuplesWithMaxElem k) [0..]`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout is one of the best answerers on this site. Be polite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for the `allTuplesWithMaxElem` function...

Suppose you want to generate all lists `[a,b,c,d]` from the numbers `[0..2]` with the restriction that 2 must appear as one of the elements.

Consider these questions:

```
If we set a = 0, what are the possibilities for [b,c,d] ?
If we set a = 1, what are the possibilities for [b,c,d] ?
If we set a = 2, what are the possibilities for [b,c,d] ?
```