# Generating a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I'm trying to create a function that generates a set of sets of tuples, but I'm new to Haskell and don't know how to implement it. Here's pseudocode of what I'd like my code to do (I'll use {} to denote set):

```
mySet :: Int -> {{(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)}}
mySet n = { {a_1,a_2,...,a_n} | P(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) }
```

The part I've written so far is the list that I'm taking each a_i from. The code is

```
firstList :: Int -> [(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)]
firstList n = [(a,b,c,d,e) | a <- [0,1,(-1)], b <- [1..n], c <- [1..(2*n)], d <- [1..n], e <- [1..(2*n)]]
```

Basically, I want to have mySet take from the list of the form

```
[(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5),(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5),...]
```

and create a list (or set, actually) that, for example when n=3, looks like

```
[[(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5),(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5),(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)],[(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5),(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5),(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)],...]
```

As far as implementations go, I'd prefer readability over speed, but ideally I'd like both.

Comment: so you have a list that contains 5-uples? like `[(1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10), ...]` and you want `mySet n` to return a subset of this list depending on a predicate `P`? Then why aren't you writing `[x | x <- originalList, predicate x]` to check one tuple at a time?  Or is the `5` in `5-uple` parametric? In this case note that you actually cannot do anything really generic because `3`-uples are a different type from `5`-uples.

Comment: Please show us the type signatures of that list you've already written code to generate and the one you're trying to build.

Comment: Hmmm, wording sounds a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949703/haskell-generate-list-of-lists before the edit...

Comment: @user348307 Put relevant information in the question itself, not in a comment below.

Comment: @ melpomene sorry I'll fix that

Comment: Perhaps, you can adapt `[ [ (x,y) | x <- [1..y] ] | y <- [1..10] ]` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us precisely how you want to do this, so we're left speculating, but a function that I have defined many times to do a very similar task takes a list of elements and breaks it into sublists of a certain size:

```hs
chunkify :: Int -> [x] -> [[x]]
chunkify n [] = []
chunkify n list = chunk : chunkify n rest 
    where (chunk, rest) = splitAt n list
```

You could then take your 12 *n*<sup>4</sup> tuples coming from `firstList n` and split them into 12 *n*<sup>3</sup> lists of length *n* via:

```hs
myLists n = chunkify n (firstList n)
```

Or if you really want to be pointfree, that's just `myLists = chunkify <*> firstList` because `(Int ->)` is an instance of a Reader-like applicative functor and the above `<*>` is defined for applicative functors in `Prelude` and/or `Control.Applicative`, depending on what version of GHC you're running.

If you want something more sophisticated you'll have to let us know; we're not mind-readers.